# How to connect a Windows 11 laptop to an external analog mixer via its 3.5mm audio output?

Tags: linux, windows, lenovo-laptop, pulse-audio, realtek-hd-audio

I am attempting to connect my Lenovo 16IAH7H W11 laptop to an external audio mixer (Behringer X802s) using the 1/8" (3.5mm) audio jack on the side. The connection is done via a TRS 1/8" to 2xTS 1/4" cable. The problem is that Windows does not recognise anything plugged into the jack *but* the headphones.

I use a dual boot setup on this laptop. Windows is there to run a handful of video games and Kubuntu is for everything else. Curiously enough, this audio jack issue does not exist on Linux, both on this laptop and on my main desktop (Manjaro) that's already connected to the mixer in the same fashion. It will still force audio through the jack if I [select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3qST.jpg) it.

[Realtek console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02cPQ.jpg) wasn't very helpful. It lacks a lot of functions and [greys out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0utQM.jpg) the jack when headphones are not plugged in.

All relevant drivers are up to date, no faults with the audio equipment.

---

**Update**: I got it to work but not in the way I am satisfied with. I had a spare 1/8" male/female extension cord and, apparently, when you plug that one in it force activates the audio jack on my laptop and the "Headphones" tab becomes visible in the Realtek audio console even if nothing is plugged in the female end of the cord.

There is some static, though. I still believe it is possible to get it to work without additional adapters like it does on Linux. My cable (Pro Snake TPY 2015 KPP) is very robust but for some reason not good enough for Windows. I would really love to avoid using this workaround and use the cable natively.

Comment: *"balanced 1/8" to 1/4" adapter"* Really? I very much doubt a low-end berigner will have balanced line ins [there's nothing I can see on the channel labelling that would indicate it has.] Do you mean TRS 3.5mm to two mono TS 6.35mm jacks? The laptop *may* be able to differentiate between a headset jack TRRS & headphone jack, TRS,  but not if the wiring [impedance] doesn't match at the other end. [[my Mac can differentiate TRS, TRRS & optical, I've little experience with 'PC's. On the Mac, if it can't figure it out, it guesses it's optical - which has infinite impedance, of course.]

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a TRS 1/8" to 2x TS 1/4". But it still doesn't explain why it works on one OS and not the other. It has got something to do with Windows because I tried it and it wouldn't work on an old W7 laptop either. However, it works on the same laptop in Xubuntu.

Comment: A Windows "problem" indeed, *for your convenience* the driver auto-detects connections and enables on-demand when something is recognized. In most Linux distros (and respective Desktop Environments) outputs can be selected even with nothing connected to it. Try **disabling auto-detection**.